# Would this solution be susceptible to overflow via thunks

Tags: haskell

The following problem is to sum consecutive integers in an array.  Here is one solution:

```
import Data.List (group)

sumConsecutives :: [Int] -> [Int]
sumConsecutives = map sum . group
```

I was wondering whether this solution would cause an overflow, and my other question was whether the runtime of the algorithm would be O(n)?  Since Haskell is lazy I assume the group function would not be called, and would be called lazily with the map, so that the list is gone over only once.  The other solution to the problem was the following:

```
import Data.List

summer :: ([Int], Maybe Int) -> Int -> ([Int], Maybe Int) 
summer ([], _) next = next `seq` ([next], Just next)
summer (xs, Nothing) next = next `seq` (xs, Just next)
summer ((x:xs), Just prev) next
  | next == prev = next `seq` (((x + next):xs), Just prev)
  | otherwise    = next `seq` ((next:x:xs), Just next)

sumConsecutives :: [Int] -> [Int]
sumConsecutives s = reverse . fst $ foldl' summer ([], Nothing) s
```

This solution tries to solve the thunk problem in the previous solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "thunk problem"? Your first solution is simple and performant. How does it not meet your expectations?

Comment: What does "overflow" mean to you? To me, it means adding up to a number so big it can't be stored in an `Int` -- which is definitely possible -- but since that has nothing to do with thunks, your title and the remainder of your question makes me think you are worried about a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you might be worried that the groups will actually be put together first, so they'll all be sitting in memory. This *could happen*. In particular, if whoever consumes the result of your function steps through the list, holding on to the beginning, *without forcing its elements along the way*, then you could potentially have a problem. This is fairly unlikely in practice, but if it's a concern in your application, you could replace `map` by the following:

```
smap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
smap f = foldr go [] where
  go x = (:) $! f x
```

This refuses to produce a "cons" before evaluating its "car". In your application, it ensures that each group is summed before the next is started, which will actually cause each group to be summed *incrementally* as long as strictness analysis and/or other optimizations work out properly.

To avoid relying on any such optimizations, you'll have to replace `sum` by

```
sum' :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum' = foldl' (+) 0
```

As for `group` itself, you have nothing to worry about—it's written lazily, so you can access (and discard) the elements of a group as that group is being formed.

---

The simplest example of an "evil consumer" I could think of:

```
forceSpine :: [a] -> ()
forceSpine [] = ()
forceSpine (_ : xs) = forceSpine xs

evil :: ([a] -> r) -> [a] -> r
evil f xs = forceSpine xs `seq` f xs
```

Comment: Is it possible for group and map sum to execute simultaneously, or does group have to fully evaluate before map sum can evaluate over its output?

Comment: @abden003, yes, they will certainly be able to interleave execution, either with your original code or with my suggested modifications.

Comment: is there a word or topic for this?  I would like to look into how haskell determines when and where to interleave.

Comment: @abden003, it doesn't decide. It's just a consequence of lazy evaluation.